# Howto add a folder to the Visalstudio library

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When opening a project in VS2019 you get this nice library added to the pick windows. It contains by default a folder, the repos under your profile. I want to add additional folders to it. How can this be done?

[image: Visual Studio open project location]

Comment: @Richard please post it as an answer. It is correct (it does not always have to be hard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a little testing it seems to be a shortcut to whatever folder you have set as your default project folder (set in Tools | Options).

And works just like other quick access entries in explorer (which also don't show child folders).